# Dynamic variable usage in ModSecurity

Tags: variables, dynamic, lamp, mod-security, mod-security2

***Brief***

I have been trying to write rules to protect a website from DoS attacks and the website have only one page `/index.php`. However, each user is identified by an unique token like this `/index.php?a=abcdef`. This page sends a lot of ajax calls that gets and posts information, periodically, as long as the user is active in the page.

***Problem***

During a DoS attack, I need to block only the specific user using the token `?a=abcdef`, which is dynamic. And the actual length of the token is around 45 characters, consisting of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. The website is visited by either a `single user` or `user group (more than 10 users)` from an IP address. The problem is, during a DoS attack, when blocking the user, I need to take the token into consideration. However, as far as I understand, unless I use a dynamic variable like, `tx.dos_counter_%{ARGS_GET}=+1`, I may not be able to identify an user uniquely. But when I reference the variable like this,`%{tx.dos_counter_%{ARGS_GET}}` to retrieve the value of the dynamic variable, it returns `null`.

***Questions***

1. Is it possible to use dynamic variables, as mentioned above, in ModSecurity?
2. Is there any other way to handle this problem?

***Miscellaneous***

This website runs on LAMP stack (Ubuntu) with ModSecurity.

Please help me solve this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: I was able to accomplish the required task in a different way with support from ModSec User Group, though, did not identify the way to use a dynamically created variable.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I used SESSION collection to store and retrieve the token and counters and this method is super easy, thanks to ModSec User Group!!!